# How to consolidate report output in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, report

I’ve got a table (“name”) with three columns (“first”, “last”, and “club”).  There are several first names that repeat themselves and several last names that repeat themselves, and 4 clubs.  Several students are in more than one club.  A small sample of data is below…

Table: name

```
 ------------------------------------
 | last     |first    |club         |
 ------------------------------------
 |Doe      |John    |Fencing Club   |
 |Doe      |Jane    | Swim Club     |
 |Doe      | Jane   |Tennis Club    |
 |Frank    |Kurt    |Computer Club  |
 |Frank    |Kurt    |Swim Club      |
 |Frank    |Kurt    |Fencing Club   |
 |Frank    |Melissa |Computer Club  |
 |Frank    |Melissa |Tennis Club    |
 |Jackson  |John    |Fencing Club   |
 |Peters   |Ashley  |Computer Club  |
 |Peters   |Ashley  |Fencing Club   |
 |Peters   |Ashley  |Swim Club      |
 |Peters   |Ashley  |Tennis Club    |
 ------------------------------------
```

What I'm looking to do it to create a concise report where I consolidate the information to show only the count of students based on the number of clubs they are in.

The output should look something like this…

```
-----------------------------
|Students| Clubs Per Student|
|2       |      1           |
|2       |      2           |
|1       |      3           |
|1       |      4           |
-----------------------------
```

Any thoughts on how I might go about constructing this?  I’ve been wracking my brain and researching for hours, but I can’t seem to come up with a workable solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select concat(last, ', ', first) as 'Student', count(club) from name group by concat(last, ', ', first)
```

But really you should give them all id#s in case there are multiple students with the same name. In which case you'd want to group by student id#.

Edit:

I misunderstood what you were looking for. You will want:

```
Select count(Student) as 'Students', clubs from (Select concat(last, ', ', first) as 'Student', count(club) as 'clubs' from name group by concat(last, ', ', first)) a group by clubs
```